# Capture lambda by value

Tags: c++, c++17

I defined a lambda in struct Baz that capture the instance of struct by value. So I expect if  modifying happened to members of struct in body of lambda it does not appear outside of lambda but it appears.
Also I define a lambda in a function (outside of struct)that  capture struct  by copy it does as I expect.
Could you please provide some clarifications about what happened to lambda inside struct?

```
 #include <iostream>
 struct Baz {
    auto foo() {
            return [=] { std::cout << s << '\n';  s = "TEST1"; };
    }
    auto foo2()
    {
            return [=] {std::cout <<"foo2" <<  s << '\n';};
    }
    auto get()
    {
            return s;
    }
    std::string s;
 };
 void test(Baz & c)
 {

     auto lambda = [=]() mutable {

         c.s = "TEST2";
            std::cout <<"InFunc:" << c.s << "\n"; // output TEST2
     };
     std::cout << c.s << "\n";//output TEST1 
     lambda();

     std::cout << c.s << "\n";//output TEST1 //here the output as expected(capture by value)
 }
 int main() {
    Baz baz{"INITSTR"};
    std::cout << baz.get() << std::endl; //output INITSTR
    auto f1 = baz.foo();
    f1();//output INITSTR
    std::cout  << baz.get() << std::endl; //output TEST1 //here i expect to got INITSTR instead of TEST1 (because the capture lambda is by value)
    auto f2 = baz.foo2();
    f2();//output TEST1
    std::cout << baz.get() << std::endl; //output TEST1
    test(baz);
 }
```

Comment: change the [=] to [&]. You want to use a reference to the variables not a copy of them. This may also help: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda ( -> lambda capture for further information)

Comment: @Creepsy please read the question carefully . I just want to know why the changes of members of  struct are seen outside the lambda despite lambda capture doing by value.

Comment: Does the pointer of struct capture by value?

Comment: please always add the language tag

Comment: `[copy = *this]() mutable { std::cout << copy.s << '\n'; copy.s = "TEST1"; };`

Comment: @Evg So my question is right that the lambda capture a pointer of struct? if yes so we have a dangle pointer if struct goes out of scope?

Comment: With `[=]` you capture `*this` by reference. If you need a copy, use `copy = *this` or just `*this`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`s` isn't a captured variable it is a member variable of the captured `this` pointer.

Due to this sometimes surising behaviour c++20 has deprecated the capture of the `this` pointer when using `[=]` captures. If you want to capture a copy of `s` you need to do that explicitly:

```
 struct Baz {
    auto foo() {
            return [s=s]() mutable { std::cout << s << '\n';  s = "TEST1"; };
    }
    auto foo2()
    {
            return [this]() {std::cout <<"foo2" <<  s << '\n';};
    }
    auto get()
    {
            return s;
    }
    std::string s;
 };
```

Note as you are modifying the captured variable you need to make your lamda `mutable`. To avoid confusion from `s` shadowing the member variable I would probably rename it:

```
return [s_copy=s]() mutable { std::cout << s_copy << '\n';  s_copy = "TEST1"; };
```

Comment: deprecated, compilers are likely to start warning about it in the near future (if they don't already), e.g. gcc complains in c++20 mode: https://godbolt.org/z/K1TsYs